# Laravel \Session::getId() getting blank sometime

Tags: php, laravel

Sometimes I am getting `null` when printing

```php
\Session::getId();
```

is there any possibility for the same or I am going wrong anywhere?

Comment: You have to do some further investigation yourself before asking a question like this. With the information you provided in your question somebody can only give you some tips and tricks and best practices for dealing with sessions in php. Which does maybe not solve your problem. Try to get it reproducible.